# Why is the preposition "in" used instead of "to"?

Tags: prepositions

The use of the preposition "in" in "in equal degree" in this sentence (what a mouthful) reads unnatural to me. Why is **in** used here instead of **to equal degree**? Although I am not sure if "equal degree" is idiomatic at all, I thought it should always be "**to** some degree".

> The inflation of the printed word has been caused, no doubt, by the exponential increase in the number of those writing, but **in equal degree** by editorial policies. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=I5gYWtcfMioC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=The%20inflation%20of%20the%20printed%20word%20has%20been%20caused,%20no%20doubt,%20by%20the%20exponential%20increase%20in%20the%20number%20of%20those%20writing,%20but%20in%20equal%20degree%20by%20editorial%20policies.&source=bl&ots=q9ehg1u9p9&sig=ACfU3U3DprPzBhUJr-qXmkZTbc4lpyy0dQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmideJ79LhAhXEnOAKHUnYB3kQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20inflation%20of%20the%20printed%20word%20has%20been%20caused%2C%20no%20doubt%2C%20by%20the%20exponential%20increase%20in%20the%20number%20of%20those%20writing%2C%20but%20in%20equal%20degree%20by%20editorial%20policies.&f=false))

Comment: Bear in mind that it is a translation from Polish. in equal degree or to an equal degree would both be fine. I have meaning issues with: The inflation of the printed word to mean: the large increase in the number of printed words.

Answer (score 2):

I'm only partially answering your question for now, since it's really difficult for me right now to nail down **"why"** it is "in equal degree", but I'm a native speaker of English (lived in the UK as a child for a good couple of years, and one of parents/ half my family are UK citizens), and the usage of the phrase is **absolutely** idiomatic (I would probably use the exact same phrase if I was writing, and intended the same meaning).

Some of the alternatives you give are possible as well, but the meaning is different - "to some degree" would work, but would mean ~ " also caused by editorial policies, with editorial policies contribution to the change being unspecified" , rather than "also caused by editorial policies, with editorial policies contribution to the change being equivalent/about the same as that of the increase of those writing" (which is the meaning in the quote you give).

Hope that helps a little already, I'll add to this answer if I can crack the "in equal" rather than "to equal" nut in my head :P.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks! Just to clarify, I wasn't suggesting "to some degree" would be an alternative to "in equal degree". I was just saying that "to some degree" would appear more idiomatic and common than the other one, and that "degree" appears to collocate more commonly with "to" than with "in".